# Resolve integral using additional equation

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, algebraic-manipulation

Usually Mathematica does a good job simplifying integrals:

```
\[Integral](um[x] qm'[x] + um'[x] qm[x] + 
    wm[x] wm'[x]) \[DifferentialD]x
```

gives the output
`qm[x] um[x] + wm[x]^2/2`.

I want to do the same thing with the expression

```
\[Integral](um[x] qm'[x] + um'[x] (qm[x] + wm'[x])) \[DifferentialD]x
```

where I have the relation `um'[x] == wm[x]`.
I've tried using the relation as an assumption:

```
Assuming[um'[x] == wm[x], \[Integral](um[x] qm'[x] + 
     um'[x] (qm[x] + wm'[x])) \[DifferentialD]x]
```

which doesn't work.
Output is `\[Integral](um[x] Derivative[1][qm][x] + Derivative[1][um][x] (qm[x] + Derivative[1][wm][x])) \[DifferentialD]x`.

Expected output would be `qm[x] um[x] + wm[x]^2/2`as above.

Comment: Something like `Integrate[(um[x] qm'[x] + um'[x] (qm[x] + wm'[x]) /. wm -> Derivative[1][um]) // Expand, x] /. Derivative[1][um] -> wm`?

Comment: Yes, this works indeed, however I am looking for a more generic way to do it. In reality the relation might be more complicated and also I might not now where to apply the replacement.

Comment: You might want to use `PolynomialReduce` and provide an ordering that forces the replacement you want e.g. higher derivatives to lower.